# Replacing all values to 1 after a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures

My current data is like below,

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1:5),t1=c(NA,1,0,0,0),t2=c(0,1,0,1,0),
t3=c(NA,0,0,0,1),t4=c(NA,NA,NA,0,0))
```

And the way I'm trying to restructure this is, 
for each id, if there's a "1" in that row, all the 0s in the subsequent columns would change to 1. (but leaving the NA as an NA).

So for id#1, nothing would change since there's no 1 in that row, but for id#2, after 1 in the column t2, any 0s afterwards would be replaced by 1.

i.e., this is what I'm trying to get at the end:

```
final<-data.frame(id=c(1:5),t1=c(0,1,0,0,0),t2=c(0,1,0,1,0),
t3=c(NA,1,0,1,1),t4=c(NA,NA,NA,1,1))
```

I've been trying different ways but nothing seems to work... I'd really appreciate any help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base R` we can apply the `cummax` by row after changing the `NA` to a lower value and then replace the value back to `NA`

```
df[-1] <-  t(apply(replace(df[-1], is.na(df[-1]), -999), 1, cummax)) * 
                NA^(is.na(df[-1]))
df
#  id t1 t2 t3 t4
#1  1 NA  0 NA NA
#2  2  1  1  1 NA
#3  3  0  0  0 NA
#4  4  0  1  1  1
#5  5  0  0  1  1
```

---

Or use `rowCummaxs` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
df[-1] <- rowCummaxs(as.matrix(replace(df[-1], is.na(df[-1]), -999))) * 
             NA^(is.na(df[-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse` you can try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("t"), names_to = "Time", values_to = "Value") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Cummax = cummax(Value)) %>%
  mutate(Value = replace(Value, Value == 0 & Cummax == 1, 1)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = "Time", values_from = "Value")
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   id [5]
     id    t1    t2    t3    t4
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    NA     0    NA    NA
2     2     1     1     1    NA
3     3     0     0     0    NA
4     4     0     1     1     1
5     5     0     0     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach in base R using `apply` row-wise could be to find out column number where first 1 occurs and replace all the 0 values after it with 1.

```
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {
               a_id <- which(x == 1)[1]
               if(length(a_id) > 0)
                 replace(x, x == 0 & seq_along(x) > a_id, 1)
               else x
           }))

df
#  id t1 t2 t3 t4
#1  1 NA  0 NA NA
#2  2  1  1  1 NA
#3  3  0  0  0 NA
#4  4  0  1  1  1
#5  5  0  0  1  1
```